# How to stop Unity C# to stop collapsing multiple spaces into one

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I have this string:

```
public string dialogueLine = "He seems happy to see\n   you.";
```

Unity automatically collapses those three spaces into one. Why, and how can I fix this? Thank you!

*EDIT*: Got it! Turns out that Unity had made the value that I'd inserted into the inspector permanent, and so when I changed the variable in the code, Unity's changed value in the inspector over-rode it.

I added this before each string:

```
[System.NonSerialized]
```

So that it didn't show up in the inspector. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Good question. Anyway it is not Unity3D that does it but Mono/.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this post](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/503922/no-breaknon-breaking-space-in-strings.html), you can use

```
\u00A0
```

Comment: Thanks. I assume that works, but it doesn't work for my particular case. I tried a few more things, and I discovered that not even \n works in my string for a new line... so I'm a little confused and trying to figure out the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use spaces, try with this.

```
public string dialogueLine = "He seems happy to see\n&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;you.";
```

Comment: Thanks. I assume that works, but it doesn't work for my particular case. I tried a few more things, and I discovered that not even \n works in my string for a new line... so I'm a little confused and trying to figure out the problem. Thank you!